# Arduino Nano Ble Sense stopped working suddenly

Tags: arduino-nano, arduino-nano-ble, arduino-nano-33-iot

My Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense stopped working suddenly a while after uploading firmware for an ML project. I've used my board for several ML projects and it worked like a charm.

I can't find the board in the Arduino IDE's port section.

I've tried to reset the board by double-pressing the reset button, but that didn't make any response, not even flashing LEDs.

I've tried changing USB cables, connecting to different ports of the PC, also other PC's but the result was the same.

I've checked the board's outputs, luckily the 3v, 5v, and Vin pins have output and run without any abnormal heating. I'm not sure what's the problem with this board. Maybe the bootloader got corrupted?

Comment: it is possible to upload to Nano BLE with Nano IoT selected and vice versa. The result is a deleted bootloader. here I describe what to do for Nano IoT, but the same applies for Nano BLE: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72955/arduino-nano-33-iot-issue/72973#72973

Comment: Thanks for giving me light Juraj.